# ASP.Net Doesn't compile AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Good Night!

I'm trying to implement a ASP.NET API, but I can't figure out why my angular doesn't compile correctly!

I just created a new empty web Project, added angular and [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)through NUGET, and I'm trying to add the scripts like this.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head ng-app="palladarApp">
  <title>CodeBranch - Palladar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="palladarCtrl">
  <div>
    <header></header>
    <section>{{ teste }}</section>
    <hr />
    <section>{{ 13 + 31 }}</section>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>

  <!--Load Libraries-->
  <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/i18n/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>

  <!--Load Scripts-->
  <script src="app/Controllers/palladarController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

PalladarController.js

```
var app = angular.module('palladarApp', []);

app.controller('palladarCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$modal', function($scope, $http, $modal) {

  $http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

  $scope.teste = "HUE HUE HUE";
}]);
```

When I run the Project, I just saw at my browser the codes..

```
{{ teste }}
{{ 13 + 31 }}
```

If I open the browser console (F12) it doesn't show any errors.

Comment: You need to add `ng-app` attribute on `<html>` tag instead of `<head>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put: `ng-app="palladarApp"` inside html tag, something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="palladarApp">
<head>
  <title>CodeBranch - Palladar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>

<body ng-controller="palladarCtrl">
  <div>
    <header></header>
    <section>{{ teste }}</section>
    <hr />
    <section>{{ 13 + 31 }}</section>
    <footer></footer>
  </div>

  <!--Load Libraries-->
  <link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/i18n/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/angular-animate.js"></script>

  <!--Load Scripts-->
  <script src="app/Controllers/palladarController.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Omg, My bad, I'm just looking for the code for like two hours and didn't saw that. Thank you